# Unexpected token doc? Firebase deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy the following firebase function. I keep getting the error `unexpected token doc` but my forEach loop is based on the google documentation. What am I doing wrong?

```
exports.sendRoomNotification = functions.firestore.document('/Rooms/{room}/messages/{message}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

// get child data

const ref = snap.ref;

const childDoc = await ref.get();
const childUsername = childDoc.data().senderId;

// get parent data

const roomRef = ref.parent.parent;

const parentDoc = await roomRef.get();
const parentName = parentDoc.data().name

console.log('parent.name => ', parentName);

// send message

const tokenRef = roomRef.collection('members')
const tokenSnapshot = tokenRef.get()

tokenSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    if doc.data().notify {
        var message = {
            notification: {
                title: 'Prizm',
                body: `@${childUsername} send a message in ${parentName}`,
                badge: '1',
                sound: 'default'
            },
            token: doc.data().fcmToken
        }

        let response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

})

Answer (score 1):

If the error was on the line `if doc.data().notify {`, wrap the condition within `()`. Or else in NodeJS it's considered as syntax error. Ex,

```
if (doc.data().notify) {
```

this will resolve the issue. If it's not in that line, try to get & update full error logs.